# Why SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory did NOT provide concurrency config?

Tags: spring, spring-jms

We can see `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` has property named `concurrentConsumers`, but `SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory` did NOT support to config it. What's the root cause? Do not recommend to use concurrency for `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the concurrency on the `@JmsListener` annotation:

```
/**
 * The concurrency limits for the listener, if any. Overrides the value defined
 * by the container factory used to create the listener container.
 * <p>The concurrency limits can be a "lower-upper" String &mdash; for example,
 * "5-10" &mdash; or a simple upper limit String &mdash; for example, "10", in
 * which case the lower limit will be 1.
 * <p>Note that the underlying container may or may not support all features.
 * For instance, it may not be able to scale, in which case only the upper limit
 * is used.
 */
String concurrency() default "";
```

Looks like the Javadocs are wrong, though

```
Overrides the value defined
 * by the container factory used to create the listener container.
```

Comment: Thx @Gary Russell ! I forgot to check this annotation.[JmsListner](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html)